# Why wont this KeyEvent work?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, jdialog, keyevent

I am making something in java that when the F1 key is hit a JDialog window to apear.My current code:

```
public class Keyboard implements KeyListener {

    private boolean[] keys = new boolean[120];

    public boolean up, down, left, right, assets;

    public void tick() {

        assets = keys[KeyEvent.VK_F1];
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {


    }

}
```

And in my main class under the tick() method:

```
keyboard.tick();
if(keyboard.assets) ac.run();
```

The keyboard variable refers to the keyboard class while the ac variable refers to this class:

```
public class AssetsChooser extends JDialog {

    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

    public void run() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

        add(fc);

        System.out.println("It works.");
    }
}
```

When I run my game and hit F1 no JDialog window appears nor does the Console display the method.

Comment: Some may question the way I setup the KeyListener and KeyEvent but I asure you nearly the same exact code works in a different program I am making.

Comment: What is `assets`? Why do you need to keep track of every single key when all you are concerned about is the `F1` key? In your `keyPressed(KeyEvent)`, why not just do `if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F1){ //open dialog }`?

Comment: Where do you define `assets`?

Comment: 1. Assets is something simmilar to minecraft texture packs with The textures and sounds in my game being customizable by picking a different folder of assets presented by the JFileChooser

Comment: sorry look above it was a copying error

Comment: if you wonder why I made an array of 120 different keys is because i will use other keys in the future\

Comment: There are a number of reasons this might not work, the most likely is related to the fact the KeyListener will only respond to the key events when the componet it is registered to is focusable AND has keyboard focus

Comment: oh sorry I have read that on so many different websites thoug read isn't as correct as the termm skimmed...

Comment: so would i add that to my main class, jframe, or jdialog...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are often focus issues related with `KeyListener` in Swing. As noted in the `KeyListener` tutorial:

> "To define special reactions to particular keys, use key bindings instead of a key listener. For further information, see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)."

An example (just hit <kbd>F1</kbd>):

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestF1KeyBind {

    public TestF1KeyBind() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        InputMap im = panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F1, 0), "openDialog");
        ActionMap am = panel.getActionMap();
        am.put("openDialog", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, true);
                dialog.setSize(300, 300);
                dialog.setTitle("Dialog");
                dialog.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestF1KeyBind();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I had also already known that KeyBidings were better than KeyListeners though keyListener is a interface while the other a class, I found it difficult to swap out.